How can I access user information on a subdomain?
I am trying to access the WordPress user from a sub-domain (not a multi-site install), but can't get the following setup to work.
The single WordPress install is on mydomain.com and I have a script on sub.mydomain.com.
In mydomain.com/wp-config.php:
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'mydomain.com' );
define( 'COOKIEPATH', '/' );
define( 'SITECOOKIEPATH', 'mydomain.com' );
define( 'COOKIEHASH', md5('mydomain.com') );

In sub.mydomain.com/helloworld.php:
header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' );
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://mydomain.com' );
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE' );
header( 'Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600' );
header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With' );

define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require_once( __DIR__ . '/../../wp-install/wp-load.php' );

echo json_encode( array('wordpress_user_id' => get_current_user_id()) );

After logging in to WordPress, I can access sub.mydomain.com/helloworld.php which returns the current user ID.
If I try to make an AJAX call from mydomain.com to sub.mydomain.com/helloworld.php, I get 0 for the current user ID.
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://sub.mydomain.com/helloworld.php",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
        console.log('res: ' + JSON.stringify(res));
    }
});
</script>

What am I doing wrong?

you should never have a standalone PHP file that bootstraps WordPress to handle AJAX requests, there's both the modern REST API and the old admin AJAX API for this. Standalone PHP files are terrible for security and can be maintenance/debugging nightmares

Found two solutions:
1)
global $current_user;
$wp_get_current_user_id = $current_user->ID;




$wp_get_current_user_id = apply_filters( 'determine_current_user', false );

Which then in helloworld.php would be return:
echo json_encode( array('wordpress_user_id' => wp_get_current_user_id) );

